# How to make npm start work on a cloned React repository?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm

I have created a new github repository with files from a working project I downloaded from another github repository of mine. I have run `npm install`. When I try `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mycomputername/.npm/_logs/2020-03-22T17_16_37_070Z-debug.log
```

I have read in other posts that the problem might be in the 'scripts', 'start' package.json file. This is what mine looks like:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-4-grid": "^3.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "use-places-autocomplete": "^0.5.4",
    "yup": "^0.28.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",              //supposedly problematic
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the start script to `"start": "index.js"` or `"start": "App.js"` as they're my main file but I have no clue whether I am doing the right thing.

If I run `npm run` this is what I get

```
Lifecycle scripts included in mycomputername:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

|                    npm update check failed                       │
│              Try running with sudo or get access                 │
│             to the local update config store via                 │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/mycomputername/.config |
```

Moreover, this repository will be shared with other people -- will they have the same problem when they clone from my repository?

Comment: Based on what you've posted, that should work. Try `npm run` to see what scripts it's picking up.

Comment: Have you been in the same directory with this project?

Comment: I get this after running npm run ```Lifecycle scripts included in mycomputername:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1```

Comment: I think you run the npm command from the wrong directory. The package.json you show has all the scripts (including start) but `npm run` only shows test as an available script.